# Coda 2 indent guides like notepad++

Tags: macos, editor, notepad++, indentation, coda

Recently switched editor and I would like to know if it is possible in Coda 2 to have indent guides like notepad++, Like this image i found: http://www.freesoftwareworkshop.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/11/notepad-plusplus.png

I am talking about the gray dotted vertical line when tabbing. I hope this is possible in Coda or some plugin i could install for it.

I have tried searching Google but its a hard example to search for and did not find any result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm currently using Coda's 2.5b8 beta and can confirm that this feature is now a part of Coda and should be included in their next release.

In the Preferences>Editor settings, there is a checkbox labeled "Show indentation guides". This is the setting you'll want checked.

As of 03/19/2014, this is only available to those with beta access.

Comment: This is great news. I would also really like to see "same word highlighting" when you select a word by double clicking, like Notepad++ does. I've been searching for a while and it doesn't look like that's currently possible in Coda 2.

Comment: Any idea when 2.5 will be released?

Comment: Sorry no idea. You can try contacting them on twitter for feature requests and maybe ask to be a part of the beta.

Answer (score 0):

I too want this feature desperately and have searched high and low to find it but with no success.

I have however put in a request with them to include this in there next major release so I'm keeping my fingers crossed.